# exported csv file contains date in mm:ss.0 format, I want in date format

Tags: excel, spring, datetime, export-to-csv, angular-ui-grid

I am having a strange problem. I am using UI grid in my UI of table view. 
When I do export to csv file, data in one of the date column shows value as 00:00:00. When I change the data format in excel sheet manually, I can see my date correctly in the column. 
To better explain, let me give an example of the problem:
In UI grid , date column shows the value: 2014:01:01, but when I do export to csv, then csv file shows date: 00:00:00.

Can anyone please help me out there. How to show the data in csv file in date format not in mm:ss:0 format.

I am using spring mvc, and mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

IN a .csv file there is no description/recognition of value types, everything is a string. So if you convert your datevalue in excel into a string of the desired format, then the .csv file will have that format in the output.

Create a new column (e.g. in column B, if column A has the date) and put in B2 (If B1 has the column name) the formula `=text(A2,"YYYY:MM:DD")`

Comment: So is there any solution for this. Date value is visible as 00:00:0 to the end user, inspite of having data as 2014:01:01.

Comment: To the contrary, i just mentioned a solution, I'll edit it to put it more verbose.